# Spring Security configuration interceptor URL handle

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

I have a problem with my Spring Boot application in security configuration. I want to apply basic authentication in a URL. My app's default URL is  `app/v1/items`
and my ap'sp secure URL is `app/v1/secure/items`.

With given configuration basic authentication is not working and I can get items from both URLs. I can not configure the `antMatchers`.

How can it handle it?

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()    
            .antMatchers("/secure").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .httpBasic();
    http
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code please.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/app/v1/items/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/app/v1/secure/items/**").hasAuthority("USER")
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.httpBasic();
    http.csrf().disable();

}
```

Comment: Yeap it is working but giving authrities in api/vi would be much nicer